# Week of the month given week of the year

Tags: microsoft-excel

How would someone go about finding what week of the month a given week is knowing only what week of the year it is?  I was going to try something like `MOD(cell,4)`, but I know this will only yield an approximate answer.

Comment: So, for example, week 52 in the year is week 4 in the month (Dec)?

Comment: @shub Yep, exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't accurately doing it without knowing the year, and which week numbering system.  Assuming it's ISO, then:

Calculate the start date of the week, given the year and weeknumber (ref. https://stackoverflow.com/a/10855872/1124287 )

```
myWeekNumDate =DATE(myYear,1,-2)-WEEKDAY(DATE(myYear,1,3))+myWeek*7
```

Calculate the weeknumber of the first of that month:

```
 myFirstWeekNum = =WEEKNUM(DATE(YEAR(myWeekNumDate),MONTH(myWeekNumDate),1),2)
```

Find the difference between your weeknum and the first of month weeknum and add one:

```
 =myWeek-myFirstWeekNum+1
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll definitely keep this in mind for future use, but for the current situation I won't be able to use it only because I don't have the year handy for each week.  Would it be better given that information to just use the approximation with =MOD()?

Comment: You could just use a fixed year or the current year.  I think it'd still be more accurate than the mod method.

Comment: For some reason it gives me the value of -47 at one point where the myWeekNumDate is December 30th.  Would you happen to know why this might be?

Comment: I can't simulate that, but it may be because I somehow dropped part of the formula for myFirstWeekNum, so it errors with missing parentheses.  Depending on how you fixed, maybe that's the issue.  I've edited the answer.

Comment: Also, I think you can't really have 12/30 be the start of the last week anyway (see wikipedia entry on iso weeks).